# Enumerate and align equation

Tags: alignment, tags, flalign

I would like to enumerate two equations in the following format

(a) For all    x     < y

(b) For all    x + y < z

that is I would like to tag/number them with a) and b) on the left, I would like to left-align them and I would like to align the x as well as the < sign.

I tried

```
    % Alignment
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    ...
    \begingroup\leqnomode
    \begin{alignat}{3}
    &\forall \quad x &&\le y  \tag{a} \\
    &\forall \quad x + y &&\le z \tag{b}
    \end{alignat}
    \endgroup
    ...
```

The alignment of the equations is great but the whole equation system is centered. I force left alignment by

```
    \begingroup\leqnomode
    \begin{flalign*}
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
    \qquad & \forall \quad x &&\le y     \\
    \qquad & \forall \quad x + y &&\le z   
    \end{alignedat} 
    &&
    \end{flalign*} 
    \endgroup
```

[image: format comparison]

but now I fail to use the `\tag` command inside 'alignedat'. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`. It can take as an optional argument the value of `\displayindent` (0pt by default, I set it to `2em`).

*Unrelated*: I took the liberty of reducing the space you added after the quantifiers, to a thick space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{array, nccmath}

 \makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\leqnomode
\begin{alignat}{3}
&\forall \; x &&\le y \tag{a} \\
&\forall \; x + y &&\le z \tag{b}
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]